# How to save to remote folders in Dolphin

Tags: networking, kubuntu, kde, dolphin

I'd like to be able to save directly to connected network folders (Google Drive, FTP connections, etc.) from applications like my browser, GIMP, etc.

In Dolphin, I have these folders listed and saved in "Places":
[image]

But, when I save a file (even one I opened from one of these locations), the network locations don't show up. Below is the file dialog:

[image]

I'm running KDE Neon 5.17.

In Nautilus on my other machine (running Pop OS), they do show up.

This means I have to take the extra step of saving to my local machine and then copying it over.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the second screenshot is the KDE file dialog? Also, it might be helpful to know what version of Kubuntu/KDE you are using, and what programs you have tried.

Comment: Thanks, @KennethHanson - yes, the second screenshot is the KDE file dialog. And I'm on KDE Neon 5.17.

Answer (score 1):

So you are using KDE based linux, but this method is not limited to KDE.

So there is tools named "KIO_GDrive", that enables KIO-aware applications (such as Dolphin, Kate or Gwenview) to access and edit Google Drive files on the cloud.

1. Just follow the instruction on this link https://community.kde.org/KIO_GDrive.
2. Open the Network folder in Dolphin and click on "Google Drive".
3. Give permission to access your google drive from online accounts.

Hope this answer help you.